# How can I get all products with special price via Magento SOAP V2 API?

Tags: api, soap, discount, special-price

I need to get all products that are at a discount. Is there any way to achieve this with SOAP API? Is it possible to compose such a filter?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :
You need to write custom api to get your desired output:

```
public function getProductDetailsByprice( )
   {
   $store_id = 1; // Use the default store
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($$store_id)) ;
 $result = array(); 
 foreach ($collection as $product) {


            $original_price = $product->getData('price');

            $discounted_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice( 
                        Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($store_id), 
                        Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getWebsiteId(), 
                        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(), 
                        $product->getId());

        if ($discounted_price != $original_price) 
            {
                    $result[] = array(
                                            'product_id' => $product->getId() ,
                                            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
                                            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
                                            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
                                            'position'   => $product->getCatIndexPosition(),
                                            'brand'      => $product->getData('brand'),
                                            'price'      => $discounted_price,
                                            'name'      => $product->getData('name'),
                                            'original_price' => $original_price
                                             );
            }
        }
    return  $result; 
}
```